# Проблемы с name у тега input, при нажатии на кнопку добавлять блок <div>

Tags: javascript, html, form

Вопрос состоит в следующем, есть некая форма (карточка) на ней есть текст филды, на каждом есть имя (по которому будет осуществляться дальнейшая связь с бд и тд).
По задумке, при нажатии на кнопку добавляется еще одна "карточка".

Код отрабатывает за исключением одного момента - всем полям присваивается одинаковое имя...
Подскажите как можно исправить это.

```
<form>
  <div id="inputi">
    <div ><input name="my_org"> 1</div>
    <div ><input name="my_car"> 2 </div>
    <div ><input name="my_phone"> 3 </div>
    <div ><input name="my_vage"> 4 </div> <br/>
  </div>

</form>
<input type="button" onclick="add_input();" value="Добавить элемент"> <br/>
<script>
  var p = document.getElementById("inputi") ;
  var length = 1 ;
  function add_input() {

    for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
      var new_input = document.createElement("input") ;
      new_input.name = "my_input" ;

      var new_input = document.createElement("input") ;
      new_input.name = "my_car" ;

      var new_input = document.createElement("input") ;
      new_input.name = "my_phone" ;

      var new_input = document.createElement("input") ;
      new_input.name = "my_vage" ;

      var div = document.createElement('div') ;
      div.appendChild(new_input) ;
      p.appendChild(div) ;

    }
    div.innerHTML = '<br>поле 2';
  } ;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var container = document.getElementById("inputi") ;

var length = 1,
    counter = 1;

function add_input() {
  var div = document.createElement('div') ;

  var delimiter = document.createTextNode("-------" + counter + "--------");
  div.appendChild(delimiter) ;

  var new_input = document.createElement("input") ;
  new_input.name = "my_input_" + counter  ;
  div.appendChild(new_input) ;

  var new_car = document.createElement("input") ;
  new_car.name = "my_car_" + counter ;
  div.appendChild(new_car) ;

  var new_phone = document.createElement("input") ;
  new_phone.name = "my_phone_" + counter ;
  div.appendChild(new_phone) ;

  var new_wage = document.createElement("input") ;
  new_wage.name = "my_wage_" + counter ;
  div.appendChild(new_wage) ;

  container.appendChild(div) ;

  counter++;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/feyeviduta/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: хорошая идея, но на демке та же беда, всем полям присваивается значение последнего ,, new_input.name = "my_vage_" + counter ; ,,

Comment: поправил.. на самом деле цикл тут лишний - из-за него все и работало неправильно. Так как переменная была *new_input*, то в цикле 4 раза вставлялся инпут с последним значением, т.е. *my_vage*

Comment: спасибо! на тот момент выход был именно таким, но теперь учту.
теперь надо придумать как подвязать базу если имена с счётчиком...